# Steepest ascent, descent gradient at a point

Tags: calculus

The problem:

For the function

$$z=x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}$$

find the direction of its steepest descent,steepest ascent, and no change at the point

$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\sqrt{2})$ on the level curve $z = 1$.

Which one of the three obtained direction vectors will point in the direction of the tangent line to the level curve? Find an equation of that tangent line.

---

What I think I found out:

The direction of steepest ascent would be the gradient, which I found to be $<cos(t),2sin(t)>$. (I hope)
The direction of steepest descent would be the negative of the gradient, or  $<-cos(t),-2sin(t)>$. 
No change happens along the function itself because $z$ is held constant.

### (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

What I don't understand:

Where should I use the point $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\sqrt{2})$ in my calculations? How does all of this lead me to find which direction vector will point in the direction of the tangent line, like the problem is asking?